# Post schedule being missed

Tags: posting

Out of the blue, my post scheduling ceased working a couple a days ago.

I tried everything I found when looking for the answer here at WordPress Answers, but none of the suggestions worked in my case.

Could anyone offer a solution to this?  I'm running the latest WordPress version and already tried disabling the plugins.

Comment: Has this stopped working completely or is it off by a few hours? Did you make any changes/updates to any files before this happened?

Comment: Zach, the scheduling had stopped completely, but the problem was solved. Please see the solution with the comment below.  Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 2):

If you are caching (parts of) your site, manually or via a plugin (such as WP Super Cache, for instance), it might have a negative impact on the functionality of `wp_cron`.
If done via a plugin, disabling it might not suffice, as WP Super Cache for example does not clear the page cache it has created upon deactivation.

If you want to keep caching active, a solution might be to setup a manual Cron Job for the php file `/wp-cron.php`

Comment: You do realize `wp_cron` is a pseudo-cron, not a real-time deamon, and apart from the name has no connection with Unix Cron Jobs whatsoever?!

Comment: What I meant was that the wp-cron.php is missing the ping and a Cron Job can be created to do so. This can happen with cache plugins caching the cron file.

Comment: Aight. Now your answer *does make much more sense* to me. Though if the OP indeed tried having all plugins disabled *while* a scheduled post was meant to be published and a user visited the site after the scheduled time, *then* I suppose caching plugins could not be responsible.

Comment: If the OP is using WP Super Cache and has deactivated it, it does not clear the page cache it has created. Also, after  deactivation, it is no longer able to delete any expired pages.

Comment: I have limited experience with that particular plugin. If that's the case with it (and others of the same kind) though, why not expand your answer by those explanations you have given in the comments?

Comment: Great Naveen!  It was indeed the caching software. I remembered that the only thing I did was to enable the 'object cache' in W3 Super Cache the day before the problems started.  I really appreciated the help.  Also thanks to Johannes for develping this discussion, which helped me understand the whole thing much better. Best...

Comment: @user31002 If this solved your problem, you can (and should) accept Naveen's answer as correct (by ticking the green checkmark below the voting buttons to the left of the answer).

Comment: I took the liberty to incorporate your explanatory comments into your answer, @Naveen. That being done, I can upvote it. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this: add the following to `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true );
```